# aws.push command not running .config commands or container_commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a simple setup with a load-balanced application and want to run some commands for cron setups (for instance, using the `whenever` gem).  However, none of my commands seem to get run on the remote server.

```
# .elasticbeanstalk/Production.config
container_commands:
  20_update_crontab:
    command: whenever --update-crontab app
    leader_only: true
```

Even tried:

```
# .elasticbeanstalk/Production.config
commands:
  update_crontab:
    command: whenever --update-crontab app
```

Is there something I am missing?  These should run with `git aws.push` correct?

When I check the logs, I don't really get any information saying it was trying to run:

```
$ eb logs | grep whenever
Using whenever (0.9.2)
```

The descriptions on this page are pretty good, just can't figure out why it isn't running.

http://www.infoq.com/news/2012/11/elastic-beanstalk-config-files

Answer (score 1):

Elastic Beanstalk configuration files should be placed in `.ebextenstions/`. It looks like yours are in `.elasticbeanstalk/`

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html

> Create a configuration file with the extension .config (e.g., myapp.config) and place it in an .ebextensions top-level directory of your source bundle.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I was trying to install libjpeg for my EC2 instance using the configuration files and it was never installed. I tried everything and was never able to find a "good solution", but I did solve it though.

**Solution**:
How to solve it? Set up a completely new Elastic Beanstalk Application and deploy the same app again. After I did this it worked from the start with the new EB App.

Check out my other answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23109410/2335675

Check it out, hope it helps for you.